# SAF role mapper not allowing access. (Liberty in CICS)

Tags: security, websphere, roles, cics

I have a web application running on Liberty in CICS of which I am trying to use SAF role mapping along with CICS authentication. I have the following EJBROLE's mapped to three users in CICS for a test: The application is named CPSM.APP

TECH.CPSM.APP.VIEWER

TECH.CPSM.APP.UPDATER

TECH.CPSM.APP.ADMIN

but when those users log into the application, It returns a 403 error for all 3 of them. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly. I will post my relevant server.xml and relevant web.xml components below.

Web.XML

```
<security-role>
    <description>Admin privileges</description>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <description>Viewer privileges</description>
    <role-name>VIEWER</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <description>Updater privileges</description>
    <role-name>UPDATER</role-name>
</security-role>      

 <security-constraint>
    <display-name>com.ibm.cicsdev.jdbc.web.SecurityConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>com.regions.cics.CPSM_Batch.jdbc</web-resource- 
  name>
        <url-pattern>/main.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/viewgroups.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/viewfileandtran.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/viewgrouptable.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <role-name>VIEWER</role-name>
        <role-name>UPDATER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>   

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>com.ibm.cicsdev.jdbc.web.SecurityConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>com.regions.cics.CPSM_Batch.jdbc</web-resource- 
   name>
        <url-pattern>/editgroup.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/addnewgroup.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/entergroup.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <role-name>UPDATER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Server.xml

```
    <featureManager>
     <feature>cicsts:core-1.0</feature>
    <feature>cicsts:defaultApp-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>

    <feature>javaMail-1.5</feature>

    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jsf-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>

    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>

    <feature>cicsts:security-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- Use SAF registry -->
<safRegistry enableFailover="true" id="saf"/>
<safAuthorization id="saf"/>
<safCredentials profilePrefix="TECH" unauthenticatedUser="LIBGUEST"/>

<safRoleMapper profilePattern="%profilePrefix%.%resource%.%role%" 
toUpperCase="true"/>
```

When I attempt to access any URL defined by the application I get a 403 error. and this error message in the sys log:

```
.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl A CWWKS9104A: 
Authorization failed for user LIBTST1 while invoking CPSM on 
/viewgroups.xhtml. The user is not granted access to any of the required 
roles: [ADMIN, VIEWER, UPDATER].
```

UPDATE: I'm adding the  referring to this application from my installedapps.xml in case it may help solve the issue.

```
 <application id="CPSM.APP" name="CPSM.APP" type="war" 
location="${server.output.dir}/installedApps/CPSM.APP.war" 
bundle="X11CPSM" token="1BEB96B000000199" bundlepart="CPSM_Batch" 
platform_id="" application_id="" appl_major_ver="-1" appl_minor_ver="-1" 
appl_micro_ver="-1">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="cicsAllAuthenticated">
            <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</application>
```

Comment: Application name is CICS, which would go in the resource part of the pattern I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. I have included a link below that explains what needs to be changed for anyone who has the same issue. For those who use CA top secret for CICS security. There is a facility control option RES that must be set to allow rules for prefixed resources, such as EJBROLES, to get loaded into the security record for a given user. If this option is set to NORES, all security checks for a given EJBROLE will fail.

Link to solution: https://comm.support.ca.com/kb/permitted-resource-receiving-tss7250e-136/kb000005323

Answer (score 1):

Your safAuthorization element is commented out - that's what enables safAuthorization (i.e. EJBRoles checking). Then also check your safRoleMapper values to ensure they map with the right prefixes to the EJBroles you created.

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.4.0/security/java/auth_app_liberty.html

Comment: Thanks for that. I feel silly. However, I uncommented it out and I'm still receiving the 403 errors

Comment: I will add some edits to show I altered that. I will also put my the full application name, may the extra period is causing an issue?

Comment: Is application binding necessary?

Comment: Update. After restarting my browser. I realized my current setup doesn't initialize a login request on startup. That may be the issue. I am about to attempt the application binding to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Update: Application binding did not fix the issue. 403 errors are still thrown.

Comment: I guess its worth mentioning that the roles in CICS are assigned via CA TOP SECRET. Not RACF like most documentation, but the methodology is similar minus the setting to "Read"

Comment: I modified it to where there is now one security constraint for all of the pages with the role-name ** , which means all authenticated users, just to test. This still throws a 403.

Answer (score 0):

When using EJBROLEs the `application-bnd` is bypassed/ignored. The mappings are held in SAF rather than the binding element. Also note, you must 'refresh' your SAF changes before starting the CICS region. I think having 'read' access to the EJBROLE (or equivalent in TOP SECRET) is a must.

I'm also wondering if you have the `resource` part of the profilePattern matching correctly, you said the App is called `CPSM.APP`. Normally the project in Eclipse (if that's your dev-env) is then reflected into the `application` element in `installedApps.xml` and has a more qualified name. One example provided by CICS is called c`om.ibm.cics.server.examples.wlp.hello.war`, and so the EJBROLE definition would be `TECH.com.ibm.cics.server.examples.wlp.hello.war.ADMIN`.

There's [more information here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.4.0/security/java/jee_app_role.html) in case I skim-read and missed anything useful.

Comment: To build on Ivan's answers, the application name according to this message is 'CPSM':

`CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user LIBTST1 while invoking CPSM on /viewgroups.xhtml. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [ADMIN, VIEWER, UPDATER].`

This would suggest Liberty is looking for the EJBRole: `TECH.CPSM.LIBTST1`.

Comment: Not sure how much help this will be, but you can also add extra logging using the safAuthorization element: `<safAuthorization id="saf" racRouteLog="ASIS" />`. For more information see: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.zos.doc/ae/rwlp_config_safAuthorization.html

Comment: My apologies. The log printed like that initially because I was having issues getting the department that runs top secret to type the EJB role correctly. The app is now CPSM.APP as the project and the prints that in the message log. I am checking for the qualified name in installed apps now.

Comment: Also in terms with the read attribute. Each user has access = ALL for their corresponding role, which I believe to be the equivalent.

Comment: I'm not too sure where the extra logging goes. It is not going to the sys log